# Dificultades para caluclar medios de mas de uno algoritmos con mean en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema : tengo el tiempo que le toma a los algoritmos BFS, DFS y A* para solucionar juegos del 15 segun sus dificultades propias. Hay varios juegos por cada nivel de dificultad). Esta capaz calcular el medio para BFS pero no lo esta para los demas y no entiendo porque...

Pueden ayudarme entender este problema?

Aqui es el codigo para escribir los resultados en writer.

```
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("result.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println("runTime DFS" + runTimesDFS);
                    writer.println("run time BFS : " + runTimesBFS);
                    writer.println("run Times AStar1" + runTimesAStar1);
                    writer.println("run Times AStar2" + runTimesAStar2);

                    writer.close();

                    meanDFS.addLast((double)mean(runTimesDFS));
                    meanBFS.addLast((double)mean(runTimesBFS));
                    meanAStar1.addLast((double)mean(runTimesAStar1));
                    meanAStar2.addLast((double)mean(runTimesAStar2));

                    PrintWriter writer1 = new PrintWriter("mean.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer1.print("d\t");
                    writer1.print("BFS\t");
                    writer1.print("DFS\t");
                    writer1.print("A*(h1)\t");
                    writer1.println("A*(h2)\t");

                    for(int i =0;i<problemSize;i++){
                        if(i<=1||i==3)continue;
                        if(i==2){
                            writer1.print(i+"\t");
                            writer1.print(meanDFS.get(0)+"\t");
                            writer1.print(meanBFS.get(0)+"\t");
                            writer1.print(meanAStar1.get(0)+"\t");
                            writer1.println(meanAStar2.get(0)+"\t");
                            continue;
                        }
                        writer1.print(i+"\t");
                        writer1.print(meanDFS.get(i-2)+"\t");
                        writer1.print(meanBFS.get(i-2)+"\t");
                        writer1.print(meanAStar1.get(i-2)+"\t");
                        writer1.println(meanAStar2.get(i-2)+"\t");


                    }
                    writer1.close();
```

Aqui es los resultados de **result.txt**:

```
runTime DFS[1002275500, -1, 30671, 30671, 201439, 201439, 130626, 130626, 613260, 613260, 150597, 150597, 230334797, 230334797, 119078, 119078, 1000880068, -1, 1000898024, -1, 1001873664, -1, 1001111309, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
run time BFS : [-1, 60196, 234840, 230154, 856084, 1249830, 223248477, 229813, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
run Times AStar1[316141, 100123, 599730, 621865, 2437748, 891661, 441231, 3304836, 448971, 10450851, 1031470, 1364444, 2150342, 1236668, 2398004, 1012777, 3577413, 930346, 1342229, 1287399, 833987, 923909, 991805, 736422, 1089391, 1529460, 2102012, 1818439, 2150166, 1362405, 2274912, 1821755, 1783043, 1497208, 1394854, 2566307, 2116257, 16251554, 1131473, 977269, 12538716, 1937947, 6316898, 1526144, 1015829, 2391290, 1061151, 4212817, 3203434, 7697831, 4004167, 11981158, 18767610, 10363610, 7720948, 5812849, 5035632, 5151903, 4242567, 11205300, 19161910, 7364846, 8246685, 10374449, 6356850, 3127472, 4460724, 4658711, 34526503, 15950820, 19204683, 3039093, 4819100, 4231508, 2774177, 3387505, 2192512, 3775054, 8767586, 6299780, 4685219, 8116913, 2962584, 3138993, 4242035]
run Times AStar2[307918, 111674, 502747, 503270, 6069636, 845279, 413490, 3172552, 544288, 2758568, 1050064, 2634507, 1503979, 1257892, 1886224, 1020397, 5118195, 667317, 1954363, 1891691, 583031, 792316, 844829, 691413, 811217, 1490068, 2100134, 1852067, 1626993, 1375678, 1540837, 2324116, 1415832, 2015665, 1459347, 2592766, 1630265, 1423187, 1100070, 13949628, 10510684, 1581410, 5928335, 3257547, 1009206, 1794131, 1033910, 4065738, 5294198, 4902085, 39496174, 6987337, 8793467, 15267404, 7290771, 4825445, 4212857, 8364815, 2500645, 22345290, 13907331, 5114238, 6964583, 12030011, 4264531, 3634794, 4771136, 2367023, 15850205, 15110779, 4679247, 3816970, 8592082, 3839918, 2827192, 3510492, 68274340, 10894103, 19928970, 5991074, 4862344, 4680440, 3192033, 3180315, 53607999]
```

Aqui es los resultados de **mean.txt file**

```
d   BFS DFS A*(h1)  A*(h2)  
2   0.25    0.0 0.0 0.0 
4   0.07142857142857142 0.0 0.0 0.0 
5   0.1111111111111111  0.0 0.0 0.0 
6   0.13513513513513514 0.0 0.0 0.0 
7   0.0847457627118644  0.0 0.0 0.0 
8   0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
9   0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
10  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
11  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
12  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
13  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
14  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
15  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
16  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
17  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
18  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
19  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
20  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
21  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
22  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
23  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
24  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
25  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
26  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
27  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
28  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
29  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
30  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0 
31  0.05154639175257732 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Y aqui es el **mean(List l)**

```
    public static double mean(List<Long> l){
    long res=0;
    for (Long val: l)
        res+=val/1000000000;
    return (1.0*res) / l.size();
}
```

Comment: Ok, esa es la salida, pero donde estarias calculando? pq el problema es q no calculas no?

Comment: @gbianchi Muchas gracias para esta observación, he anadido el codigo de `mean(List<Long> l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es que un `long/long` da un long. `l1/l2` con l2>l1 da 0.
Entonces el verdadero codigo seria:

```
double mean(List<Long> l) {
  double res = 0;
  int t = 1;
  for (long val : l) {
    res += (val - res) / t;
    t++;
  }
  return res /1000000000;
}
```